# Consumir una API con axios usando React js

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando consumir una API que he creado de un dominio propio. Mi idea es simplemente que pueda acceder a la información a través de una URL desde React empleando axios.

El problema con el que me encuentro es que recibo un error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

El código que empleo es el siguiente:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class News extends React.Component {

    state = {
        articulos: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('URL').then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({articulos: res.data})
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>Iepa pues</h1>
    }
}

export default News;
```

Donde `URL` es el enlace donde se encuentra toda la información en formato json. He hecho pruebas con este mismo código usando otros enlaces y no me ha dado ningún problema, pero con el de mi dominio me sale el error que comentaba antes.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que revises el código de tú api, y agregues la cabecera Access-Control-Allow-Origin con valor * a la respuesta que envías de vuelta al cliente, de esta forma podrás realizar peticiones a tu api desde orígenes diferentes.
Sería una buena idea que pudieras revisar la temática de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).